# Using array elements in neo4j WITH statement

Tags: neo4j

I want to load data into Neo4j from JSON. For my `:Timeline` node I need to calculate an id from the `id` property of the first element of an `events` array property.

```
with {json} as data, {json}.service + {json}.events[0].id as timelineId
merge (timeline:Timeline { id: timelineId })
on create set timeline.responseTime = data.responseTime
```

However I get an error:

```
neo4j.ClientError: [Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax] Invalid input '.': expected whitespace, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, AS, ',', ORDER, SKIP, LIMIT, WHERE, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 55 (offset: 54)) "with {json} as data, {json}.service + {json}.events[0].id as timelineId"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably just operator precendence,

can you try

```
with {json} as data, {json}.service + ({json}.events[0]).id as timelineId
merge (timeline:Timeline { id: timelineId })
on create set timeline.responseTime = data.responseTime
```